# Filter and delete key values in json array

Tags: angularjs

Had generated one json array using the filter.

```
orders = filterFilter(vm.gridOptions.data, {
                                sampleId: 295
                        });
```

Here I filtered my  orders array and I got this.

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": 51491,
      "orderDate": "2016-12-19T13:35:39",
      "regId": 1354,
      "sampleId": 295,
      "name": "Test",
      "nameAr": "Test"
    },
    {
      "orderId": 51493,
      "orderDate": "2016-12-19T13:35:39",
      "regId": 1354,
      "sampleId": 295,
      "name": "Test",
      "nameAr": "Test",

    }
  ]
}
```

Can I filter in way, It should keep only one field in the orders array.
Using angular filter I need to do this.

I need an array like this.

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": 51491
    },
    {
      "orderId": 51493
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, not using angular's filter filter. It filters. It doesn't map. But Array.map() is your friend (and Array.filter(), too, BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, You can iterate through the `orders` to generate the array of objects having `orderIds`. Like this,

```
$scope.orderIDs = [];
angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(order){
    $scope.orderIDs.push({
        "orderId": order.orderId
    })
});
```

Answer (score 6):

When you need to transform object to another, use Array.map() method.
You can use it together with Array.filter() method to filter results.

```
orders = vm.gridOptions.data
    .filter(function (x) {
        return x.sampleId === 295;
    })
    .map(function (x) {  
        return {
            orderId: x.orderId
        };
    });
```

The above function returns an array of objects that contain only orderId property and sampleId is equal to 295.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Jarek answer above and implemented in my code:
In my case, I had an array of file names with other details but I wanted to reduce it only names. So I first filtered array that has names begins with "sharath/subDir/12345678-"

```
filesList.filter(t => t.name.startsWith("sharath/subDir/123456789-")).map(x => {return x.name})
```

Hope it might help someone.